# Apache Metamodel has retired. Alternatives?

Tags: metamodel, apache-metamodel

Apache Metamodel has moved to the attic. why it is moved and what are the alternatives?

Comment: anyone if has any input please share with me I am stuck in my project because of this.

Comment: There is an active fork here: https://github.com/datacleaner/metamodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still continue to depend on MetaModel, it just won't be maintained by Apache. It's also used by several other projects (most notably - I think - by [DataCleaner](https://datacleaner.github.io)) so maybe creating a fork with a less formal governance model around it would be an option that other communities would appreciate. I help maintain DataCleaner and was heavily involved in Apache MetaModel and would love to at least have a repo set up where we can contribute dependency upgrades, bug fixes and such.